# Why a program can run with a dynamic library not found?

Tags: linker, dynamic-linking, hana, dynamic-library, ldd

After installing `SAP HANA` successfully, I can see the `sapstartsrv` process run:

```
# ps -ef | grep sapstartsrv
xn1adm     2143      1  0 Mar29 ?        00:00:05 /usr/sap/XN1/HDB00/exe/sapstartsrv pf=/home/hana/shared/XN1/profile/XN1_HDB00_dhe2 -D -u xn1adm
```

But after using `ldd` command to check `sapstartsrv` dynamic linking libraries:

```
# ldd /usr/sap/XN1/HDB00/exe/sapstartsrv
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd35a30000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd1fe6b3000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fd1fe4ab000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fd1fe270000)
    libpam.so.0 => /lib64/libpam.so.0 (0x00007fd1fe061000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fd1fde5e000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fd1fdc59000)
    libsapnwrfccm.so => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd1fd8d7000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd1fd5d6000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd1fd3bf000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd1fd1a2000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd1fcdfb000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd1fe8b7000)
    libaudit.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007fd1fcbd8000)
```

I can see the `libsapnwrfccm.so` is not found. But why `sapstartsrv` program can run with a dynamic library not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because something starts that program by pointing the linker to the directory containing that library. Usually this is done my setting the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. For example:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/look/here/for/libs program
```

The runtime linker will now also look in `/look/here/for/libs` to find libraries `program` depends on.